# Gravitational potential of infinitely thin square

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, potential

Suppose a square with constant area density $\sigma$ with a side $d$ and an object which is located on a distance $h$ from the plane of square.

What is the gravitational potential of the object when it's located just abovve center of the square, center of its side and on the angle.

My attempt

I decompose square into elementary parts of mass $dm=\sigma dx dy$ and integrate over them. For every of 3 cases

$U_1=Gm\sigma \int^\frac{d}{2}_{-\frac{d}{2}}\int^\frac{d}{2}_{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{dx dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}}$

$U_2=Gm\sigma \int^d_0\int^\frac{d}{2}_{-\frac{d}{2}}\frac{dx dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}}$

$U_3=Gm\sigma \int^d_0\int^d_0\frac{dx dy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+h^2}}$

Where $m$ is the mass of the object. But those integrals are not trivial and I don't know how to solve them. Is there an easier method for that?

Comment: “Just above” probably means you can take $h$ to be zero. And you could try a different coordinate system.

Comment: Is using a computer algebra system to do integrals disallowed?

Comment: I would start with a circular plane of radius $R$ to get a feel for what to expect, to see how it depends on $R$ and $\frac{h}{R}$.  The integration would be much easier.

Comment: @Ghoster Well, it is given that h<<d, but that doesn't mean it could be said to be zero, since the potential would diverge. Also, I am not sure, what other coordinate system one can use, because that is a square and the easiest way to define it is using cartesian coordinates

Comment: You cannot assume $d$ is so large that $h$ doesn't matter.  Just as electric field due to an infinite sheet of uniform charge density is uniform throughout space above the sheet, Electric force would be uniform if you treat the sheet of mass as essentially uniform.  If potential energy is considered to be zero at an infinite distance, this would produce an infinite potential energy.  As you move away from the finite mass sheet, you will eventually reach a distance at which the sheet begins to look like a point charge, so U=0 at an infinite distance can work.

Comment: No, it doesn’t diverge when $h=0$. (Yes, I have evaluated it.)

Comment: The easiest way to set up an integral is not necessarily the easiest way to evaluate it. The integral simplifies greatly in a non-Cartesian coordinate system.